# Angular 6 project with libraries using rxjs5

Tags: angular, rxjs

I'm trying to my project to newer Angular version. Newer Angular use rxjs 6, but my project uses some third party's libraries which still use rxjs5. How to deal with this case?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you that when update your angular version you also do it with the rxjs version separately to see if that works.

```
npm update rxjs@version
```

In version, you should choose any version, for example:

```
npm update rxjs@6.0.0
```

Let me know if its work

Comment: Thanks! I'll try later and update